# "qsub script.sh" yielding "Unknown queue" error

Tags: pbs, qsub

Let say I have two bash scripts. (small.sh & super.sh)

small.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /current_path/
chmod a+x *.sh
bash super.sh
```

super.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
qsub test.sh
```

When I submit my job to PBS system.

```
qsub small.sh
```

The super.sh could not be executed. 
That means it will not

```
qsub test.sh
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the error your are getting ??

Comment: Did you try `bash ./super.sh` instead?

Comment: @NikhilFadnis `qsub: Unknown queue` Here is what I got.

Comment: It seems like I can not queue any jobs from computer nodes. I can only submit it from mother node.

Comment: Yup..thats what even i found out... posting answer for future reference.

Comment: It sounds like the problem isn't specific to bash at all; would happen even if you were using qsub to run non-bash scripts (or invoking qsub *from* a non-bash script), and could be rewritten to focus on the `Unknown queue` message -- no?

Answer (score 1):

If your script has no `#PBS` directives, and you don't submit with something like `qsub -q batch ...`, then it seems like you either a) have no default queue defined, or b) the queue name being submitted to does not exist (or has a typo). Run this (as an admin) to see the default queue:

`qmgr -c 'print server default_queue'`

Run this to see the queue settings:

`qmgr -c 'print queue <queue_name>'`

If you have no default queue, then either set one, or make sure to always submit directly to a queue with `qsub -q <queue_name>...` (and of course make sure the queue actually exists, which you can still do with `print queue` as mentioned.

Comment: It may also help to see the exact error text when doing the job submission.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i found out from [here](https://www.nas.nasa.gov/hecc/support/kb/common-reasons-for-being-unable-to-submit-jobs_197.html) :

Queue is Unknown

Be sure to use the correct queue. For Pleiades jobs, use the common queue names normal, long, vlong, and debug. For Endeavour jobs, use the queue names e_normal, e_long, e_vlong, and e_debug. The PBS server pbspl1 recognizes the queue names for both Pleiades and Endeavour, and will route them appropriately. However, the pbspl3 server only recognizes the queue names for Endeavour jobs, as shown below:

```
pfe20% qsub - q normal@pbspl3 job_script
qsub: unknown queue
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more ? In my example, I could not see how file name influences the queue.

Comment: The script you are firing would run if you had the priviledges to run `qsub`. The error states that the problem is not in `bash` but `qsub`.